# RTCPeerConnection.createAnswer callback returns undefined object in mozilla for WebRTC chat

Tags: webrtc, mozilla

Following is my code to answer the incoming call:

```
var pc = connection.pc;
pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp,function() {
 pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
  pc.setLocalDescription(answer,function() {
   // code for sending the answer
 }) 
 })
})
```

The above code works fine for chrome, but when i run the same in mozilla, the `answer` obtained from `pc.createAnswer` callback is `undefined`. As a result of which it gives me following error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of RTCPeerConnection.setLocalDescription is not
>   an object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're not checking errors, specifically: not passing in the required error callbacks.

`setRemoteDescription` and `setRemoteDescription` require either [three arguments](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#legacy-interface-extensions) (legacy callback style) or [one](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCPeerConnection) (promises), but you're passing in two. Same for `createAnswer` minus one.

The browser's JS bindings end up picking the wrong overload, returning you a promise which you're not checking either, effectively swallowing errors.

Either add the necessary error callbacks:

```
var pc = connection.pc;
pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp, function() {
  pc.createAnswer(function(answer) {
    pc.setLocalDescription(answer, function() {
      // code for sending the answer
    }, function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
  }, function(e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
}, function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Or use the modern promise API:

```
var pc = connection.pc;
pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp)
  .then(() => pc.createAnswer())
  .then(answer => pc.setLocalDescription(answer))
  .then(() => {
    // code for sending the answer
  })
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

The promise API is available natively in Firefox, or through [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) in Chrome. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aynr0k5q/).

And always check for errors. ;)