# How do I render the video cam display on an html page using WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to create a rudimentary face time-like application, but I am having difficulty displaying the box for the video cam display on my front end. My back-end server code seems to work, but truthfully, I am not sure as I have not been successful with any results on my frontend. I have provided my client.js, server.js, and my index.html files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Server.JS**

```
//requires
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// express routing
app.use(express.static('public'));


// signaling
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('create or join', function (room) {
        console.log('create or join to room ', room);

        var myRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room] || { length: 0 };
        var numClients = myRoom.length;

        console.log(room, ' has ', numClients, ' clients');

        if (numClients == 0) {
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('created', room);
        } else if (numClients == 1) {
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('joined', room);
        } else {
            socket.emit('full', room);
        }
    });

    socket.on('ready', function (room){
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('ready');
    });

    socket.on('candidate', function (event){
        socket.broadcast.to(event.room).emit('candidate', event);
    });

    socket.on('offer', function(event){
        socket.broadcast.to(event.room).emit('offer',event.sdp);
    });

    socket.on('answer', function(event){
        socket.broadcast.to(event.room).emit('answer',event.sdp);
    });

});

// listener
http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

**Client.JS**

```
// getting dom elements
var divSelectRoom = document.getElementById("selectRoom");
var divConsultingRoom = document.getElementById("consultingRoom");
var inputRoomNumber = document.getElementById("roomNumber");
var btnGoRoom = document.getElementById("goRoom");
var localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");

// variables
var roomNumber;
var localStream;
var remoteStream;
var rtcPeerConnection;
var iceServers = {
    'iceServers': [
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com' },
        { 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
    ]
}
var streamConstraints = { audio: true, video: true };
var isCaller;

// Let's do this
var socket = io();

btnGoRoom.onclick = function () {
    if (inputRoomNumber.value === '') {
        alert("Please type a room number")
    } else {
        roomNumber = inputRoomNumber.value;
        socket.emit('create or join', roomNumber);
        divSelectRoom.style = "display: none;";
        divConsultingRoom.style = "display: block;";
    }
};

// message handlers
socket.on('created', function (room) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then(function (stream) {
        localStream = stream;
        localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        isCaller = true;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('An error ocurred when accessing media devices');
    });
});

socket.on('joined', function (room) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then(function (stream) {
        localStream = stream;
        localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        socket.emit('ready', roomNumber);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('An error ocurred when accessing media devices');
    });
});

socket.on('candidate', function (event) {
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
        sdpMLineIndex: event.label,
        candidate: event.candidate
    });
    rtcPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
});

socket.on('ready', function () {
    if (isCaller) {
        rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
        rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
        rtcPeerConnection.onaddstream = onAddStream;
        rtcPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
        rtcPeerConnection.createOffer(setLocalAndOffer, function(e){console.log(e)});
    }
});

socket.on('offer', function (event){
    if(!isCaller){
        rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
        rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = onIceCandidate;
        rtcPeerConnection.onaddstream = onAddStream;
        rtcPeerConnection.addStream(localStream);
        rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));
        rtcPeerConnection.createAnswer(setLocalAndAnswer, function(e){console.log(e)});
    }
});

socket.on('answer', function (event){
    rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));
})

// handler functions
function onIceCandidate(event) {
    if (event.candidate) {
        console.log('sending ice candidate');
        socket.emit('candidate', {
            type: 'candidate',
            label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
            candidate: event.candidate.candidate,
            room: roomNumber
        })
    }
}

function onAddStream(event) {
    remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    remoteStream = event.stream;
}

function setLocalAndOffer(sessionDescription) {
    rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    socket.emit('offer', {
        type: 'offer',
        sdp: sessionDescription,
        room: roomNumber
    });
}

function setLocalAndAnswer(sessionDescription) {
    rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    socket.emit('answer', {
        type: 'answer',
        sdp: sessionDescription,
        room: roomNumber
    });
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>FaceTime</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>FaceTime</h1>

    <div id="selectRoom">
        <label>Type the room number</label>
        <input id="roomNumber" type="text" />
        <button id="goRoom">Go</button>
    </div>

    <div id="consultingRoom" style="display:none">
        <video id="localVideo" autoplay></video>
        <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you describe what behavior you expect, what's wrong and what specific error messages, if any, you're seeing?

Comment: There are no error messages, which leads me to believe there is not an issue on the backend, as all of my backend server logic also makes sense. @jib

Comment: After launching my server in the command prompt, I expect to be able to type in the same room # in two chrome tabs and see myself rendered as a live video stream on my screen. What actually occurs is once I do go into the same room, for example, say "123" in two different tabs, I do not see a live stream of myself. The only thing I see is a blank white page with my html header tag, which reads "FaceTime"..@jib

Comment: @jib is this info sufficient enough for you to diagnose my issue?

Comment: Have you opened the web console on the client? `createObjectURL` no longer works with streams. See point 5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53269679/918910). Also, your ICE signaling seems overly complicated, and that mozilla STUN server no longer exists.